# how to add github repo to an npm package?

Tags: npm, package-managers, npm-scripts

Looking at this image,

[image]

My new package doesn't have this link. I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Do you set `"repository"` in your `package.json`? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository

Comment: nope, that was the problem. maybe is better to create an answer out of this. Thx.